# coverting TSQL to Oracle setting parameters

Tags: oracle

I started a new job and needing to learn Oracle for the job.  I am trying to convert this simple code so I can build more complex queries down the road

DECLARE @NPI = VARCHAR(20)

SET @NPI = '123456789'

SELECT *

FROM AFFILIATION

WHERE NPI = @NPI

I am trying to figure out to set parameters in Oracle and then use them in the WHERE statement or other places within the code.

I think I have figured out part of my question but not sure of the full conversion

DECLARE NPI1 varchar(20):= '123456789'

I am looking to set verables/parameters and use them later in the code.  YES I dont need it in this query but If i know how to use it for the query I can build much more complex Oracle queries.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [bind variable](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A81042_01/DOC/sqlplus.816/a75664/ch34.htm):

```sql
VARIABLE npi VARCHAR2(20);
```

Then use PL/SQL to set its value:

```sql
BEGIN
  :npi = '1234567890';
END;
/
```

or `EXEC`:

```sql
EXEC :npi = '1234567890';
```

Then you can use it in your query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   AFFILIATION
WHERE  NPI = :npi
```